# How to prevent simultaneous access of two applications to the one database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

Imagine that you have an application that have access to SQL Server 2012, so it reads data from one table, process it and writes result to another table.
If you launch two such applications simultaneously on different computers the resulting data will be doubled.
The question is:
How to prevent this situation?

Please provide you examples with Transact-SQL and C#.

Comment: Way too broad. There are plenty of different ways to do that, each with pros and cons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set some state in the DB that informs applications that a processing task is being performed. (I assume it's ok for both applications can run one after the other with no side-effect, or the same app can run twice)

The application will then check this state and refuse to run if its set.

Alternatively, you can lock an entire table so the 2nd instance cannot read (or write) data using the [isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173763.aspx).

Comment: Do you mean that Read-Table should have additional column which will contain a flag meaning that current row was already processed?

Comment: you can do that, or you can set a 'global' "task is processing data" flag in a table, eg a configuration table.

Comment: We used to have an ETL process - lots of apps importing and converting data. They would each write a step (eg starting, importing data set, importing file, processing, copying data, etc) into a table. Then you can see progress of the application tasks as well as using it to prevent concurrent runs.

Comment: I see many problems with such an architecture, the most important one being on relying on client to tell if an operation is being performed. I think it would be much better to introduce a tier between clients and data that will isolate the database and deal with ongoing operations, regardless of which client started it.

Comment: @Crono all you've done is pushed the problem to a different layer - now the services will have to detect if operations are in-progress in (probably) the same way. Depending on the situation (ETL for example) then this would not help matters much.

Comment: @gbjbaanb still it will give much more power to control simultaneous access. You can make sure only the service can connect to the database.

Comment: @Crono, how you will organize this tier?

Comment: @AntonAgapov in short, I'd make a service acting as the only possible gate to write data. From it, I would manage user sessions and detect calls for specific tasks. This way, regardless of which client is calling for tasks, you know which ones are currently running and you can refuse a request for a second execution. Having this behavior centralized is far better than spreading it through your different clients, as there cannot be issues caused by having different apps or different versions of a specific app out there.

Comment: @AntonAgapov when I last did ETL properly, all the load functionality to the DB was via stored procedures. These were the ones that included the restriction. A loader application read the data from files and sent it to the sprocs with the loaded tables not being accessible from outside the DB. Putting this restriction in the DB itself means you have no issues with clients ignoring it :) Also, when the data is finally loaded, you copy it to a publicly visible table so client can read it. Then you ensure 100% uptime even while you're loading new data.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to lock the corresponding tables while one application is doing it's job.

More info here: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-locking-in-sql-server